# Getting Swift app to work locally with an unsigned certificate

Tags: swift, nsurlrequest

I'm trying to set up my app to work with a local version of our API which uses an unsigned certificate that Xcode *hates*.

I've been doing research and tried a number of approaches that haven't worked from me, from editing the Info.plist file to extending NSURLRequest with a static function to set the undocumented `allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost` to return true every time.

Nothing's been working and most resources are either out of date with deprecated APIs or just aren't helpful.

Would love any recent things that anyone has found to make this work. Thanks

Comment: I needed to set up App Transport Security Settings in info.plist. Did you set NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads for your local domain and add an exception?

Comment: Have you tried putting this in your plist file ?  `<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide the error but I think ATS (App Transport Security) restricts you using your domain. You need to add an exception and you don't even need an unsigned certificate in your local since this exception will allow HTTP API access.

In the Info.plist, create the following entry - assuming domain.localdomain.com is your local domain:

```
App Transport Security Settings --- Dictionary
    Exception Domains           --- Dictionary
        domain.localdomain.com  --- Dictionary
            NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads --- Boolean = YES
```